# Source code changes in kubernetes, SaltStack & Docker in production and locally

Tags: vagrant, docker, salt-stack, kubernetes

This is an abstract question and I hope that I am able to describe this clear.

Basically; What is the workflow in distributing of source code to Kubernetes that is  running in production. As you don't run Docker with `-v` in production, how do you update running pods.

In production:
Do you use SaltStack to update each container in each pod?

Or

Do you rebuild Docker images and restart every pod?

Locally:
With Vagrant you can share a local folder for source code. With Docker you can use `-v`, but if you have Kubernetes running locally how would you mirror production as close as possible?

If you use Vagrant with boot2docker, how can you combine this with Docker `-v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you shouldn't "distribute source code", you should rather "build and deploy". In terms of Docker and Kubernetes, you would build by means of building and uploading the container image to the registry and then perform a rolling update with Kubernetes.

It would probably help to take a look at [the specific example script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/f44bb9d673529ac9b38c66a5fb49b572034a19a1/examples/update-demo/4-rolling-update.sh), but the gist is in the usage summary in current Kubernetes CLI:

```
kubecfg [OPTIONS] [-u <time>] [-image <image>] rollingupdate <controller>
```

If you intend to try things out in development, and are looking for instant code update, I'm not sure Kubernetes helps much there. It's been designed for production systems and shadow deploys are not a kind of things one does sanely.